# Shadow box em imagem React Native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Estou tendo dificuldade para colocar um `shadow` na imagem, tentei colocar na `View` e na `Image` mas não funcionou.

```
<View style={styles.ContainerImageProfile}>
    <Image style={styles.ImageProfile} source={{uri: 'profile.png'}} />
</View>

ContainerImageProfile: {
        width: 90,
        height: 90,
        borderRadius: 50,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginTop: 100,
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        shadowRadius: 50,

    },
    ImageProfile: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando usar isso para Android? esses atributos de Shadow são suportadas somente pelo IOS, como você pode verificar em: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/shadow-props.html

como alternativa você pode usar usar o atributo de estilo `elevation`, por exemplo:

```
ContainerImageProfile: {
       ...
       elevation: 1
       ...
    }
```

senão, acredito que somente com uma biblioteca de terceiro